# Exception when making webservice call

Tags: java, ssl, jboss

I get the following exception where I make a webservice call.
What is the meaning of this exception?

```
2015-01-19 17:01:56,549 ERROR
[org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS] (Timer-11) SOAP request 
exception: java.io.IOException: Error initializing socket factory SSL 
context: Cannot validate the store URL: D:/ProgramData/RTS/shared/netcore/certificates/netflower.keystore
```

Comment: your keystore under D:/ProgramData/RTS/shared/netcore/certificates/netflower.keystore for the SSL connection is either missing or invalid

Comment: Made a minor edit to hopefully prevent more downvotes

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're trying to make a connection over SSL (i.e. https) and the server could not load the keystore file because: a) the file path is invalid; b) the file is password-protected and an invalid password or no password was supplied; c) file is corrupted.

If the file is really there you can use the following command to verify if it's readable: `$JAVA_HOME\bin\keytool -list -v -keystore D:/ProgramData/RTS/shared/netcore/certificates/netflower.keystore`

Comment: The keystore exist at specified path and its not currupted

Comment: Check if your container has visibility of this path. This exception is thrown if the **validateStoreURL** method of the following class returns false, which in this case happens if the program could not locate the file.

http://www.docjar.org/html/api/org/jboss/remoting/security/SSLSocketBuilder.java.html